# Remove item border in actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have added a social sharing button to actionbarsherlock via the built-in process for doing so.  That sharing item shows up with a border around it.  How can I remove that border?  I don't know if the border is in the 9-patch images, styles, themes, or what.  For all I know it could even be a default Android style.  Can someone please point me to where I can change it?

The XML for the menu is below:

```
<item 
   android:id="@+id/show_share_menu" 
   android:title="Share Menu"
   android:actionProviderClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.ShareActionProvider">
```

Answer (score 2):

You might create your own app theme by extend from Sherlock Theme and override `activityChooserViewStyle` with blank (null) background style like this

```
<style name="Theme.CustomTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="activityChooserViewStyle">@style/ActionBar.ActivityChooser</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.ActivityChooser" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActivityChooserView">
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
</style>
```

or use default Sherlock Activity Chooser style like this

```
<style name="Theme.CustomTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="activityChooserViewStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActivityChooserView</item>
</style>
```

Then change your application theme in AndroidManifest.xml to your custom theme.